# GUI testing tool for windows mobile application

Tags: windows, user-interface, testing, windows-mobile

Can somebody suggest me an open source GUI testing tool for windows 7/6.5 mobile applications?? N any idea on usage of Microsoft's UI Automation framework for windows mobile application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight Unit Test framework is probably what you're after for Phone 7 (there is no "Windows Mobile 7").  For 6.x I'm not aware of anything (that I'd recommend anyway).

Comment: Thank you ctacke :) ..But i have one more question for u :p .. I googled about Silverlight Unit Test Framework. I couldn't find any useful info , if it could be used for UI automation.. Is it only for unit testing or does it support UI testing also ??

Answer (score 2):

Try NUnit, Its the Best one to End your Search

http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/

Regards
Ravindran Antonysamy